# Parsing a variable into a sql statement in Python

Tags: python, sql

I have the following insert statement that let me parse sql query into a python file and then returning a dataframe of that data that is collected from the query

```
   params = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};' \
     'SERVER=localhost;' \
     'PORT=XXX;' \
     'DATABASE=database_name;' \
     'UID=XXX;' \
     'PWD=XXX;'

   params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(params)

   db = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s' % params)

   sql = '''
   select * from table_name
   where column_name= variable_in_python
   '''

   dataframe = pd.read_sql_query(sql, db)
```

Now, after the 'where' statement, I want to have a variable that I declare in Python, for example an id-number (let's say 1123581321). This variable needs to come in that 'variable_python'-place.

I tried:

```
   import pyodbc as py
   import urllib
   from sqlalchemy import create_engine
   import pandas as pd 

   x = 1123581321

   params = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};' \
     'SERVER=localhost;' \
     'PORT=XXX;' \
     'DATABASE=database_name;' \
     'UID=XXX;' \
     'PWD=XXX;'

   params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(params)

   db = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s' % params)

   sql = '''
   select * from table_name
   where column_name= 'x'
   '''

   dataframe = pd.read_sql_query(sql, db)
```

This obviously doesn't work. But I have not a single idea how I can do this (if it can be done).

Any suggestions are more than welcome!

Comment: Try using [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) (or any other string formatting mentioned in that article)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `?` as a [placeholder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-perform-parameterized-queries?view=sql-server-ver15) in the query and pass the value as a parameter to the `read_sql_query` function:

```
sql = '''
select * from table_name
where column_name= ?
'''

dataframe = pd.read_sql_query(sql, db, params=(variable_in_python,))
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the answer by @blhsing.

Another way is f-strings. I particularly like them because they make things very readable.

For example:

```
# Query Parameters
column_name = 'x'
```

and then:

```
sql = f'''
select * from table_name
where column_name= {column_name}
'''
```

You could go further with this and use a dictionary of parameters and call each one by key within the f-string itself. The advantage of this method is that if you have a lot of parameters for longer and more complex queries, you always have a dictionary to refer to. Another is that when you do a `print(sql)` in this case, you can see exactly what parameters you are passing (this helps in the case of longer queries with more parameters).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
sql = '''
   select * from table_name
   where column_name= {}
   '''.format(variable_in_python)
```

For more information, have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html